# Scrolling Button On Scroll View with Middle Button Selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Please guide me on how can I create a dynamic button a scroll view that will be scrollable, with the middle button always selected.

like this

---

```
b1    b2   b3   b4   b5(selected)     b6   b7   b8     b9
```

---

if user select b4 it should seems like that

---

```
      b1   b2   b3   b4(selected)     b5   b6   b7     b8
```

---

```
b2   b3   b4   b5    b6(selected)   b7   b8     b9
```

---

the way should like that. Please guide.